# How to get text from cmd using autoIT

Tags: autoit

I am new to AutoIT and would like to know if there is any way of getting the text from the output.
Please refer the screenshot for more clarification.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Where that screenshot comes from? Is that a separate application, or a command line (console)? You mentioned "from the output", so [StdoutRead](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StdoutRead.htm) might be the solution (without knowing more details).
**** UPDATE**
Based on the answer - this is a separate app, which seems to write to standard output. You might try the following

If you want to process the text whenever it appears, process it inside the while loop. In that case keep in mind, some text might be even being printed, means they might be incomplete.

```vb
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
$App="C:\Your\Path\To\App.exe"
$PID=Run(@ComSpec & ' /C "' &  $App & '"',@TempDir, @SW_HIDE, $STDIN_CHILD + $STDERR_MERGED)

$output=""

While ProcessExists($PID)
    $output &= StdoutRead($PID)
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

MsgBox(0,"Ready","Read from other app's StdOut: " & @CRLF & $output)
```

**** UPDATE 2**
Seems you would like to interact with your application not just read from there (according to your comment below). Using Send() function is not the best choice as that sends the text to the window which is in the front. You have to start the application with Run() which gives you its process ID, then use StdinWrite() and StdoutRead() to send/receive texts. Here is a bare example returning your domain and username:
[image: result read from stdout]

```vb
#include <Constants.au3>
Local $PID = Run("cmd.exe", @SystemDir, @SW_SHOW, $STDIN_CHILD + $STDOUT_CHILD)
StdinWrite($PID,"whoami" & @CRLF) 
$output="" 
While ProcessExists($PID) 
    $output &= StdoutRead($PID) 
    Sleep(1000) 
WEnd 
MsgBox(0,"Ready","Read from other app's StdOut: " & @CRLF & $output)
```

Comment: Hi @Attila, Thanks for the comment. Actually this is a seperate application. I was just using a reference of the cmd.

Comment: Hi @Attila, I used the following code. $PID= ShellExecute("") While ProcessExists($PID)
    $output &= StdoutRead($PID)
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
 
MsgBox(0,"Ready","Read from other app's StdOut: " &$output). The code is going in infinite loop.

Comment: Also, How do we get specific text as the screen also has other texts as well?

Comment: You can compare the $output variable's content by using StringInStr (https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringInStr.htm) or StringRegExp (https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm). 
I do not know the amount of text output by your application - if that's a larger amount you might consider to empty out the $output variable every x seconds / minutes.

Comment: Hi Attila, the issue is that when I run the above code it is going in infinite loop. Hence I am not able to get any value in the $output.

Comment: It shows as  "/ErrorStdOut ""

Comment: As mentioned, if you want to process the output during runtime, put your processing code into the while loop. You can set up some rules when to process - e.g. when string starts with JP0006. Also you might increase the sleep value to 1 second (1000). First I'd suggest to print the value of $output somewhere so you can see its content.

Comment: I tried the following code #include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Local $PID= ShellExecute("cmd.exe")
Sleep("10000")
Send("VC99")
Send("{Enter}")
$output=""
While ProcessExists($PID)
    $output &= StdoutRead($PID)
    Sleep(1000)
WEnd
MsgBox(0,"Ready","Read from other app's StdOut: " & @CRLF & $output) Still no output in $output.

Comment: See my updated post which includes an example code how to interact with an application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256790/discussion-between-sijo-john-and-attila).